# Participation on a bounty

Tags: support, bounties

I posted an answer on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135260/sql-query-to-produce-xml-output/9191377#9191377) with a bounty, but when I go to my profile and click on bounties, I see:

> 0 Active bounties
>   You have not participated in any bounties.

Shouldn't I be participating on the one I answered the question?

Comment: Which one?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135260/sql-query-to-produce-xml-output/9191377#9191377

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You participated *in a question that had a bounty*, you haven't yet participated *in a bounty* itself which is one of the following:

- Offering a bounty
- Winning a bounty (which may happen yet, for that answer you left)

Comment: so that section only shows the ones I offered or the ones I won? I thought that "active" meant the ones I was participating.

Comment: @Diego nope, "active" means bounty or bounties you offered and is/are still active. (Bounty is active for 7 days at most)